# R - Loop over several files

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I want to apply this code on several lists of dataframes (df).

```
df1<- lapply(df1, function(x) {
  x$Date <- as.Date((x$Date), format="%Y-%m-%d")
  x})
```

The dataframe lists are called `df1`, `df2`, `df3`, `df4` and `abc1`, `abc2`, `abc3`, `abc4`. The Date-column is always on the same place.

I tried this to get the `df1-4` done, but it doesn't work.

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  df[i] <- lapply(df[i], function(x) {
  x$Date <- as.Date((x$Date), format="%Y-%m-%d")
  x})}
```

I also thought about getting all the filenames into a list and looping with that:

```
df_list = c("df1","df2", "df3", "df4", "abc1", "abc2", "abc3", "abc4")
```

But I haven't succeeded with that. I want to keep the original names of the files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `df1` a data.frame or a list of data.frames? Could you provide an example of your data?

Comment: All are a list of dataframes

Comment: @DSGym: Its a list of dataframes!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i in 1:length(df_list)) {
  df_list[[i]] <- lapply(df_list[[i]], function(x) {
    x$Date <- as.Date((x$Date), format="%Y-%m-%d")
    x})
}
```

Does this work for you?

For me it does:

```
class(df_list[[1]][[1]]$Date)
[1] "Date"
```

Your error seemed to happen because you used `[]` instead of `[[]]`. You have to use double brackets to refer to the data.frame.

Comment: This will return new list. I think OP wants modification of existing variables (i.e. in-place modification).

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error message: Error in x$date : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: maybe because your variable is `Date` not `date`. It anyway seems to be a bit trickier.

Comment: Can you provide some example data?